# Not connecting to AWS DynamoDB with client builder in wowza

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, wowza

I am trying to connect to DynamoDB in wowza using latest Amazon sample with latest SDK.

I have added logs before and after the connection. I can only see the logs before connection. Alos, there is no error getting throwed.

Can some one help me on this?

This is the code snippet.

```
logger.error(MODULE_NAME + " Before CLient");
client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
        .build();
dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
logger.error(MODULE_NAME + " After CLient");
```

The sample is working in windows wowza. It is not working in linux wowza.

Comment: Did you assign the same IAM role to both the windows and linux machine?

Comment: Yes. Same IAM role. I am using secret key and access Id to connect to dynamo

Comment: I dont know how you are definie the credentailsProvider but you could remove and let it look up the whole chain

To do this, you instantiate an AWS Service client without explicitly providing credentials to the builder, as follows.

client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                       .withRegion(Regions. US_EAST_1)
                       .build();
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html